# Does the "Iron Will" perk add will bonuses randomly?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

From the wiki:

```
Iron Will - §200

Soldiers receive a larger Will bonus each time they are promoted.
(Adds between 2-10 extra Will increases per promotion on top of the default +2)
```

Does this bonus of 2-10 occur randonly or is it based on something like performance during the mission(s)?

Comment: I've been tracking it and so far there does not seem to be a pattern, it does indeed seem completely random.

Comment: you should post it as an answer then

Comment: yea, I probably should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further testing, it appears that the amount of Will received as a bonus during promotions is random, within the range of 2-10. This means you will always get at least +4 Will from a promotion, with the possibility of anything upto +12.

Comment: This is incorrect.